# make install, to a temporary location

Tags: raspberry-pi, autoconf

I am building couchdb, it has a `./configure` (created with autoconf). I then can do a `make && make install`. The problem that I am having is that the installed files have absolute paths embedded in them.

My preference would be for these paths to be relative. Failing that I would like to tell the `make install`, where the program will finally be installed.

I am creating the program outside of its final location of `/usr/local`. This is because I will copy it into a docker container. (This must be a problem encountered by anyone making `deb`s, `rpm`s or other install packages.)

Answer (score 0):

> My preference would be for these paths to be relative.

Doing so might have application security implications.

> Failing that I would like to tell the `make install`, where the program will finally be installed.

The `configure` script has a lot of paths you can customize.  The common ones are [detailed here](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/Directory-Variables.html), couchdb may have others that will be documented in the output of `./configure --help`.

Setting the `prefix` path is fairly standard for packagers, e.g. `./configure --prefix=/usr ...` will install install the software to `/usr` instead of `/usr/local`.  Usually `rpmbuild` .spec files (or their debhelper equivalents) will end up setting the prefix path at least.

Comment: I first used `--prefix=…`. It put it where I expected, but with the absolute paths. So it was not relocatable. I did get it to work by bind mounting over `/usr/local`, but that will only work if you have root access, and would be unsafe on a multi-user machine. As it would hide `/usr/local`, this last point may be possible to overcome, with namespaces. I have thought about building it in `docker`, as docker can do a similar trick, or `fakechroot`. Any tips?

Comment: I don't understand a couple things due to lack of details in your description.  [CouchDB has packages](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/install/unix.html) for lots of different systems, which could be installed to a container using a Dockerfile, if the one that comes with your preferred Docker image isn't recent enough.  So why isn't this solution possible?  Are you needing to modify CouchDB sources?  I'm not seeing the requirement that CouchDB _must_ be built yet, just that it's your current strategy to get it into your Docker container.

Comment: There is now couchdb build for raspberry-pi (Arm processor). So I am building from source.

Comment: Prebuilt [docker images](https://hub.docker.com/r/treehouses/couchdb/) for CouchDB on the Raspberry Pi platform also exist.